# Unable to handle showModalDialog window in Selenium Webdriver(Java)

Tags: java, iframe, selenium, webdriver, showmodaldialog

I am automating a web application using Selenium webdriver(java). I have handled popup windows in other parts of application but i'm not able to handle showModalDialog window. Application has read only text box and I have to fill this by clicking Search button, which will open new popup window.

HTML code for this Textbox and Serach button is as follows.

```
 <tr>
 <td><label class="classLabel">Textbox<sup class="mandatory">*</sup></label></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="textbox" value="" readonly="readonly" class="someTextbox">
 <img src="/Some/url/search.gif" alt="Select Help" onclick="launch2()" />
 </td>
  </tr>
```

After clicking Search button, a showModalDialog window will open and there I have to click a radio button to fill text box.

This showModalDialog window has iframe element and below is html code for this.

```
  <iframe src="/some/url.do?parameter=getData" width='100%' height='100%' border=0 >  
  </iframe>
```

Below is the code I'm using to switch into popup window and select iframe. Here, test case is simply stopping after clicking Search button and popup window also appearing but it is not handling popup.

```
     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"Select Help\"]")).click();
     String winHandleBefore = myD.getWindowHandle();        
       for(String winHandle : myD.getWindowHandles()){
       driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
       driver.switchTo().frame(0);
           driver.findElement(By.name("hier_data_id")).click();
```

If anybody have idea on how to handle showModalDialog windows, it would be really helpful. Suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have edited my question.Earlier I thought it was popup window, but after researching I came to know that it is showModalDialog window.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

private static String popUp;
```

//get window handle before popup

```
Set<String> beforePopUp = driver.getWindowHandles();
    //do the click
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"Select Help\"]")).click();


  //get window handles after the click
Set<String> afterPopup = driver.getWindowHandles();

    //remove all window handles before the popup
 afterPopUp.removeAll(beforePopUp);
if(afterPopUp.size() == 1) {
popUp = (String) afterPopUp.toArray()[0];
 } else {// there might be more than on popups that might have been triggered by the click...do some error handling here}


 //switch to popUp
driver.switchTo().window(popUp);

//do your stuff
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply, I edited my question. The window i was not able to handle is showModalDialog window. Please share if you have idea on how to handle showModalDialog windows.

Comment: If the window gets the focus after you do the click..then you should directly be able to interact with the elements on the window...try inserting some wait time before you find your iframe in the window...

Comment: Now i'm able to interact with showModalDialog window elements only on IE Driver , I referred some workarounds provided in Selenium discussion page . Firefox driver and Chrome driver does not support showModalDialog window it seems. There is an issue still open(Issue 284) for this.

Comment: Downvoting for incorrect information. The opened popup window is not guaranteed to be the second one in the list returned by getWindowHandles(). The handles returned are not ordered, especially for the IE driver. Correct your answer and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @JimEvans ..Iterating over the windows and assuming that the second one is pop up was my quick and dirty trick to interact with the elements on the popup .I don't normally use it in my code but didn't really know that about the the order issue. I am glad you brought up the issue. Thanks.